# Segue causes UITabBarController to shift status bar up in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm having a weird issue in regards to how I'm restricting screen orientation.

Here's what my storyboard looks like:

[image]

I have screen orientation set to **Portrait** only.

In my AppDelegate, I have the following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask
{
    if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is VideoPlayerViewController
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
    }
    else
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }
}
```

In the Home Tab, clicking either the Red play button or any of the cells will perform a segue to my `VideoPlayerViewController`. I have restricted the `VideoPlayerViewController` to landscape only.

However, right before the segue occurs, this occurs:

[image][image]

Basically, what is happening is that in the 2nd picture, the red portion shifts up, pushing the status bar out of the way.

Then in the 3rd picture, the first 2 tabs are shifted slightly to the **left** while the last 2 tabs are shifted slightly to the **right**.

Once again, all of this occurs right before a Modal segue occurs.

What could be causing this? Let me know if I need to include additional code..

Comment: Could you tell us about the constraints you have set in the storyboard?

Comment: There's a lot of constraints. I can possibly post a sample code on github to allow you to see and help debug the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an attempt to remove as much irrelevant code as possible to post a sample code on github for others to help debug, I've found the culprit of my issue.

It is related to `override func prefersStatusBarHidden()` in my code, causing the status bar shift and now been resolved.